# How to return Interface Collection objects using C#

Tags: c#, interface

I have the following Interface and I want to return the interface collection to the client application.

```
public class myClass:IDetails
{
    private int id;
    private string name;

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            id= value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name= value;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I forming the object using the following code

```
IDetails obj = new myClass();
obj.ID = 100;
obj.Name = "Bill"
```

I read that I can use IEnumerable to return the interface collection, Thanks for your help

Comment: Your are not using any collection...

Comment: Thanks, I will try to update my code by using the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many structures implementing `IEnumurable`. Examples are an array or a `List<T>`.

For instance:

```
IDetails[] det = new IDetails[1];
List<IDetails> details = new List<IDetails>();
det[0] = new myClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just *create* a collection required and *initialize* it with items:

```
  IDetails[] array = new IDetails[] {
    new myClass() {ID = 100, Name = "Bill"},
    new myClass() {ID = 101, Name = "John"},
  };

  ...

  // if you want IEnumerable<T>
  IEnumerable<IDetails> items = array;
```

Or

```
  List<IDetails> list = new List<IDetails>() {
    new myClass() {ID = 100, Name = "Bill"},
    new myClass() {ID = 101, Name = "John"},
  };

  ...

  // if you want IEnumerable<T>
  IEnumerable<IDetails> items = list;
```

Or

```
  Dictionary<int, IDetails> dict = Dictionary<int, IDetails>() {
    {100, new myClass() {ID = 100, Name = "Bill"}},
    {101, new myClass() {ID = 101, Name = "John"}}, 
  };

  ...

  // if you want IEnumerable<T>
  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, IDetails>> items = dict;
```

etc. I hope you see the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IEnumerable<IDetails>` for that purpose like

```
IEnumerable<IDetails> objList = MethodtofilltheList();

return objList;
```